# How to repeat a table every x rows - google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, repeat, schedule

I need to repeat a table every x row.

Here is what I have :

Auto Populate a Table [image: Click to see the IMAGE]

---

(1) I want to auto-populate 
(2) this table
(3) 'x' times
(4) Every 'y' rows

I've try with *offset*, *sequence* , *importrange* and *arrayFormula* but I don't find a way to do it !
But I'm sure it's possible to do it.

*I do this to help doctors make their schedules.*

Comment: how do you calculate the begin and end times for each row ? or do you want to repeat the table with the 9 workstations x times? (like 13*9+4)

Comment: By seeing this example this is what I get. You want to auto-populate **INFOS** 120 times with a middle blank space (9 rows). Could you please share your sheet so it's easier to reproduce accurately the expected behaviour.

Comment: Thank's guys here is the link
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Zq-uE1vD7xTjknZgVMAmdLimpYK3ezOsKI_oEesUb2E/edit?usp=sharing 

@JoseVasquez : I want to avoid blank cells because after that it will be difficult for me to use the query function as I want.

Comment: @nabais : "Begin" and "End" could change. This is the time when you start working (or finish)

Answer (score 1):

I tired to think differently (See Solution 2)
[>Open my Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Zq-uE1vD7xTjknZgVMAmdLimpYK3ezOsKI_oEesUb2E/edit#gid=1412657093)

Instead of ducplicate the table n times

I auto-populate : (x days) * (x workstations)

```
=ARRAYFORMULA("1"&T(SEQUENCE(DATES!B3*INFOS!K2)))
```

THEN in another column I add (+1 day) every (x workstations)

```
=DATE(YEAR(DATES!$B$1);MONTH(DATES!$B$1);DAY(DATES!$B$1)+INT((ROW()-2)/INFOS!$K$2))
```

AND now I have to repeat my list of workstations until the end of the column (but I'm still looking how).

[image]